# Dynamics CRM Unexpected Error when trying to view Prospects/Leads

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

We have a user who has been unable to view his Leads/Prospects when trying to view his default list.  He can search for them and get them to display in search results but whenever he tries to view his default entry screen we get an 'Unexpected Error'.

I have pasted the system error report below.

Any suggestions?  It looks like a data error to me, but I cannot work out where to look!

Thanks in advance!

```
Exception generated at: 29/10/2014 17:11:45
Error Type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Error Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Error Stack Trace: 
    at CommunicationActivityServiceBase.AutoCreateContactOrLead(BusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context, String subject, AddressEntry[] fromAddressEntries, AddressEntry[][] allResolvedAddressEntries)  ilOffset = 0x241
    at EmailService.Deliver(Boolean userPromote, Guid emailId, String messageId, String subject, String from, String to, String cc, String bcc, DateTime receivedOn, String submittedBy, String importance, String body, BusinessEntityCollection attachments, Guid campaignResponseId, Entity emailDeltaEntity, ExecutionContext context, Boolean validateBeforeDeliver)  ilOffset = 0x2C9
    at EmailService.DeliverIncoming(String messageId, String subject, String from, String to, String cc, String bcc, DateTime receivedOn, String submittedBy, String importance, String body, BusinessEntityCollection attachments, Entity extraProperties, Boolean validateBeforeCreate, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xB8


Stack Frame: 

    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1C5
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE4
    at ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)  ilOffset = 0x16E
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse, Boolean checkAdminMode)  ilOffset = 0x1F1
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode)  ilOffset = 0x2D
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode)  ilOffset = 0x26
    at OrganizationSdkService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)  ilOffset = 0xD
    at   ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)  ilOffset = 0x241
    at DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)  ilOffset = 0x100
    at ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)  ilOffset = 0x48
    at ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)  ilOffset = 0xC6
    at MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)  ilOffset = 0x62
    at ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)  ilOffset = 0x256
    at ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)  ilOffset = 0xF1
    at ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)  ilOffset = 0x39
    at AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0xC2
    at ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)  ilOffset = 0x55
    at AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0xC2
    at AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)  ilOffset = 0x21
    at InputQueue`1.Dispatch()  ilOffset = 0x121
    at ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)  ilOffset = 0x22
    at IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)  ilOffset = 0x5
    at _IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)  ilOffset = 0x3C


Exception Data: 
    1: Key type: System.String, value: PluginTrace

Custom Message: Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: d0cabb1b-ea3e-db11-86a7-000a3a5473e8; EntityName: email; Stage: 30; MessageName: DeliverIncoming; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel.CommunicationActivityServiceBase.AutoCreateContactOrLead(BusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context, String subject, AddressEntry[] fromAddressEntries, AddressEntry[][] allResolvedAddressEntries)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel.EmailService.Deliver(Boolean userPromote, Guid emailId, String messageId, String subject, String from, String to, String cc, String bcc, DateTime receivedOn, String submittedBy, String importance, String body, BusinessEntityCollection attachments, Guid campaignResponseId, Entity emailDeltaEntity, ExecutionContext context, Boolean validateBeforeDeliver)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel.EmailService.DeliverIncoming(String messageId, String subject, String from, String to, String cc, String bcc, DateTime receivedOn, String submittedBy, String importance, String body, BusinessEntityCollection attachments, Entity extraProperties, Boolean validateBeforeCreate, ExecutionContext context)
.
```

Not sure if this helps any?  Error reported when user tries to do an advanced search within prospects/leads --

Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): RoleBasedViews.Plugins.SavedQueryPreRetrieveMultiple: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't know where the code is?  I am new to Dynamics and have been tasked with looking after our install.  Is this a bespoke module that's reporting the error?  If so I may be able to find the code, if not I'm a bit stuck.  Sorry if I am not being very helpfull!

Comment: check your plugins regarding to Leads/Prospects and Emails, as the error message complains about email deliver incoming

Comment: Thanks Jorge, will do.